Why does the command npx prisma db push not progress and fail to push my models to Supabase?
When I run npx prisma db push, the command does not proceed beyond this part. I've been waiting for almost 30 minutes, and it doesn't progress further.
C:\Users\matti\Documents\Weso\Proyectos\X-Informar>npx prisma db push
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma\schema.prisma
Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database "postgres", schema "public" at "aws-0-sa-east-1.pooler.supabase.com:6543"

This is my schema in case there's any error. I want to push these models to Supabase, and I'm not sure if that's affecting the process. The same issue happens when I try prisma migrate.
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id       String   @id @default(uuid())
  nombre   String
  email    String   @unique
  password String
  role     UserRole @default(USER)
  news     News[]
}

enum UserRole {
  USER
  ADMIN
}

model News {
  id         String  @id @default(uuid())
  titulo     String
  contenido  String
  visibility Boolean
  userId     String
  user       User    @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
}

What could be wrong? Is there an issue with my models? Do I need to change anything to push the models to Supabase?
The only commands I ran were:
npm install @prisma/client
npx prisma init
I created the models, and then I tried to run npx prisma db push.
